# Angular apply style to the first visible item in ngRepeat

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list generated by ngRepeat, like so

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="data in tree | filter:key">
        {{data.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

and I want the first item in the list to have rounded corners. I have a style such as

```
.first-item {
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

How can I cause this style to be applied to the **first visible** item? Note that the `key` is connected to a search box, so the first item is dynamic.

Comment: It probably easier to handle using CSS and `:first-child` selector.

Comment: @Stubb0rn you are right! i should have thought of that, but I guess I had angular on the brain. Also i was assuming that the filter works using "display:none"... but it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the css rule first-child:

```
.list-group li:first-child { 
     border-top-left-radius: 15px;
     border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me.  Using `ng-class="{'first-item':$first}"` does not work for me, because bootstrap already has a selector `.list-group-item:first-child` which is apparently more specific.

Answer (score 6):

use $first, that represents the first iteration within a ng-repeat

```html
<ul class="list-group">
    <li ng-class="{'first-item':$first}"
class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="data in tree | filter:key">
        {{data.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

edit: since `first-item` has a dash, it must be in quotes

Comment: @SasiKiran yes. it works. Thanks. But I also had to change the borders in my class to !important. there is a conflict with another class in the bootstrap css. That is why i prefer Bastien's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Pure Angular Way would be:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="data in tree | filter:key track by $index" ng-class="{MyClassName: $index == 0}">
        {{data.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

or see answer of Sasi Kiran ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $index variable value to do such conditional formatting within ng-repeat. Here's an example:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" 
        ng-repeat="data in tree | filter:key" 
        ng-class="{'first-item': $index == 0}">
        {{data.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $first and ng-class. $first is a property which is exposed on the local scope, for each item in the repeated list. It's value is true if the item is the first one in the repeated list. The HTML should look something as below:

```
<ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="data in tree | filter:key" ng-class="{'.first-item': $first}">
    <div>{{data.name}}</div>
</li>
```